# In Oracle SQL is there a way to join on a value twice?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have two tables, with the following columns:

cars

```
motorcycle_id | fuel_id | secondary_fuel_id ...
```

fuel_types

```
fuel_id | fuel_label | ...
```

In this case fuel_id and secondary fuel_id both refer to the fuel_types table.

Is it possible to include both labels in an inner join? I want to join on the fuel_id but I want to be able to have the fuel label twice as a new column. So the join would be something like:

```
motorcycle_id | fuel_id | fuel_label | secondary_fuel_id | secondary_fuel_label | ...
```

In this case I would have created the secondary_fuel_label column.

Is this possible to do in SQL with joins? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just join twice:

```
select c.*, f1.fuel_label, f2.fuel_label as secondary_fuel_label
from cars c left join
     fuel_types f1
     on c.fuel_id = f1.fuel_id left join
     fuel_types f2
     on c.fuel_id = f1.secondary_fuel_id ;
```

The key point here is to use *table aliases*, so you can distinguish between the two table references to `fuel_types`.

Note that this uses `left join` to be sure that rows are returned even if one of the ids are missing.